# Run feature action from canvas for overlapping polygons

Tags: qgis, actions, menu

I have a polygons layer for which I created an action, using a python script, that allows me to open a file related to the feature that I click on the canvas.
However some of the polygons features overlap, some being included in the area of others (I use a transparent style to see them all).
When I click the Run Feature Action button and then click on the overlapping polygons it pops a small menu with a list that contains the 'fid' of each overlapping polygon and the 'All features' option.
[image]

How can I have the menu display instead of the 'fid', for example, the name of the polygon features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the field used to display this value in the list of the identify tool for any layer.

> Each feature is described by the name of a field along with its value. This field is the one set in Layer Properties ► Display. All the other information about the feature follows. [link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#using-the-identify-features-tool)

[image]